# How can I install Gnome Builder IDE?

Tags: ide

[Builder](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Builder) is a IDE for gtk development, how can I install it on elementary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not install Gnome Builder on elementary, because it requires GTK 3.16, while elementary uses GTK 3.14.

Comment: so well when will we be able to try hands on it?

Comment: @Adityaultra Assuming this answer is right, when Gnome backport the IDE (unlikely) or when elementary upgrades GTK (Loki, a year or two) or when we figure out how to run it without first ruining everything (Cassidy James is looking into this right now).

Answer (score 3):

As of 0.4 loki you can install gnome-builder 3.18 from the software repositories.

Comment: nice. try it now out